# Who is kAlAgni Rudra?

Tags: shiva, kashmiri-shaivism

In Sri Rudram invocation AnuvAka 1 hymn 28, we get the following verse -

> ... Namaste astu bhagavanh vishveshvaraya mahadevaya tryambakaya
>   tripurantakaya trikagni kalaya **kalagnirudraya** nilakanthaya mrutyunjayaya
>   sarveshvaraya sadashivaya shrimanmahadevaya namah 
>   Let my salutations be to that great God who is the Lord of the universe; the great
>   God who has three eyes and who destroys Tripura, the three Asura cities.
>   To that God who is the Dandhya time when the three sacred fires are lit; who is
>   Rudra the fire that consumes the universe; whose throat is blue; who has
>   conquered death; the Lord of all; the ever auspicious one; salutations to that
>   glorious and great God.

Now, In Kashmiri Shaiva books, at many places he has been mentioned like this-

> In Viravali also it is said:
>   "Observe that divine consciousness present in the body which
>   has the glow like that of **kalagni Rudra** and in which all things
>   are dissolved and the multitude of the elements is burned."

Also from Vijnanabhairava tantra-

> "One should think of one's body being burnt by kalagni4
>   arising from the toe of the right foot. At last there is the realization
>   of light which is santa, i.e. in which there is not the slightest
>   trace of difference.(Verse 52)

also, from the notes of Shiva Sutra by Jaidev Singh

> Kalagni Rudra is the deity full of tejas i.e. burning light.
>   In the human body, his place is supposed to be the toe of the
>   right foot. One has to meditate that Kalagni is arising from that
>   place and burning the entire body.

Also, he is said to be residing in **Nivritti KalA**

> Kalagni: Kalagni-bhuvanesa - a particular Rudra in Nivrtti
>   kala.

but I want some scriptural information on KAlAgni Rudra.

Comment: Where does the first paragraph you quoted occur in Sri Rudram? I know it as an invocatory prayer before starting the chant of Rudram. Does it occur in the Rudram?

Comment: @NogShine No it's not there.

Comment: @Nog Shine It's not in Samhita but it's there in Shiva Rahasya where Karitikeya has fully commented upon Sri Rudram... so it's perfectly fine to say It's part of Sri Rudram...

Comment: @Tezz But still a commentary is different from Veda itself.

Comment: @Tezz https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.vedaunion.org/static/pdf/Sri-Rudram-Text-Anuvakam-1-11-devanagari-transliteration-translation.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjj4sb21sXYAhVKuo8KHUsgD40QFgg3MAM&usg=AOvVaw2KbME0LnjEb-ZuUUCHhaL4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kalagni Rudra is one of the  name of Lord Shiva (Rudra) **who resembled the fire of kala.** . The name Kalagni Rudra also  means **" he who is burned the Kala"** ( the time , who is  cause of  the perpetual destruction of objects). Shiva burnt the deity Kala with his "Third Eye" , who came to took away the life of " King Sveta" , who was great devotee of Lord Shiva , while worshiping him .

The story of Kalagni Rudra is in detail mentioned in [**Skanda Purana**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-i/chapter-32/topic-1)    - Book one -Mahesvara khanda  Section one - Chapter 32 -" Burning of Kala"Page no 273.

Here are the excerpts from   Skanda Purana -:

King Sveta was constant and faithful devotee of Lord Shiva. He ruled his kingdom righteously . And he ruled the earth for many years.
After many years , when time came Yama the god of death sent his messanger to that king  , Chtragupta instructed the messengers.

> **18-19** Once yama sent his messengers to that king who was worshiping
> shankara , the bestower of the greatest aim in life (i.e salvation).
> At the instance of Chitragupta messengers were deputed and instructed
> " Let sveta be brought"

The messengers of Yama came to the temple , but they were unable to carry out the command of yama i.e dharma.Then Yama himself came there to carry out the job ,but he himself were unable to do so.

> **21-23** Then the messengers could not carry  out the command of dharma.
> After knowing this , Yama himself came there. He suddenly lifted his
> baton and was desirous of taking the king away.The deity of great arms
> saw the king engaged in the meditation of shiva .

> **24-26**  Immediately
> the king of dead ones became excessively agitate and remained
> (motionless) as though he was printed in picture.

Then at the scene arrived the mighty "kala" the time , who causes the destruction of all objects.The Yama was fearful after seeing the kala. Then Kala asked Yama why the king was not taken away and ordered yama to quickly follow his orders. Then the Yama replied.

> **29** I shall do according to your command. This devotee of shiva cannot
> be tackled by us.

Then the kala himself  took the charge and rushed to kill king Sveta.

> **30** on hearing Yama's words , Kala became infuriated. Hurriedly he took up the sword intending to kill the king.

> **31-36** The king is
> thinking about the foot of Shiva who is of the nature of supreme being
> , and the cause of salvation and complete identity on form . Kala was
> rushing at him and was seen by Sadashiva , the slayer of kala. The
> rouge was approaching him undeterred arrogantly. **When he was seen
> midway between himself and nandikeshwara by shiva , the lord of the
> universe , the affectionate kinsman of devotee , he was stared at with
> the Third eye by the great lord who wanted to protect his devotee. He
> became reduced to ash in an instant.**
>
> **38-40** The king then regained consciousness and looked again and again at kala who had come to kill him and then was burnt by fire.
> Without being excited , **who prayed to Rudra who resembled the fire
> of kala.**

---

The Brahmavaivarta Purana  Brahma khand - Chapter -8 also mentions Kalagnirudra.Here its said that Rudra appeared from forehead of eraged Brahma.

> अविर्भुता ललाटाच्च रुद्रा एकादशा प्रभो |
>   कालाग्निरुद्र: संहर्ता
> तेषामेक: प्रकीर्तित: ||19||
>
> This enraged Brahma ,  the creator of the universe. O lord , on
> getting enraged , Brahma , a Rudra appeared out of hhis forehead he is
> said to be Kalagni Rudra.