# Does God know about all our actions and also whatever we talk?

Tags: vishnu, gods, philosophy

Omniscience means He should know everything including all our actions and whatever we talk. Is this correct?

<sub>Link to the recently [deleted question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30059/1049).</sub>

Comment: This is same as your previous question and you already know that omniscience means knowing everything. What is the question here?

Comment: From where does actions arise? Thoughts. From where do we humans speak? from thoughts. So its same question you have asked in different words.... Vote to close! Also you have answered your own question in body of the question!

Comment: Related:  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27875/who-records-karma-of-all-living-beings

Comment: I am not sure why ur Q got so many downvotes. It is a good Q simply bcoz the scriptures describe clearly the answer in them.

Comment: @Rickross, because the same user had already asked [same Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30059/1049), few hours before this. When that was about to be closed as duplicate, he/she deleted it and copy pasted again here as this Qn. BTW I think the user may done it out of inexperience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes God knows even what you talk secretly. See the following Atharva Veda (AV) Mantra:

> Dvau samnishadya yat mantrayete rAja tat veda varunah tritiyah ||
>
> When you talk in secret, there is always the third observer, divine
>   observer Varuna.
>
> **AV 4.16.2**

So, God is monitoring all our actions, even though we might think that we are doing those actions secretly.

The following three Manu Smriti verses make things even more clear.

> 8.84. ’The Soul itself is the witness of the Soul, and the Soul is the refuge of the Soul; despise not thy own Soul, the supreme witness of
>   men.
>
> 8.85. ’**The wicked, indeed, say in their hearts, "Nobody sees us;" but the gods distinctly see them and the male within their own breasts.**
>
> 8.86. **’The sky, the earth, the waters, (the male in) the heart, the moon, the sun, the fire, Yama and the wind, the night, the two
>   twilights, and justice know the conduct of all corporeal beings.’**

So, yes Gods very well know what we are doing or talking although we might be thinking that we have done those actions "secretly".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be more particular, by God is meant the Supreme Brahman, sometimes personified as Krishna or Narayana. Whereas Varuna is the god of water and is a lower level deity, and one of the devas. What is your answer with regard to the Supreme God and not lower level deities?

Comment: Supreme Brahman is situated in all of our hearts so he is antaryami and witness of all our thoughts .. Varuna is a Vedic deity and much revered in the Vedas.. So it is not right to label him as a lower level deity.. anyways, it is Varuna who does the job of monitoring. @user15740

Comment: See my updated answer.. The Brahman indeed knows all our actions, thoughts .. Here Brahman is referred to as "male in the heart/breast" @user15740 So, this convincingly answers the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, He knows everything, each and every detail of each n every soul. References from our scriptures have already been stated above in one of the answers by Rickross, but just adding something more to that.

Each and every minute details be it words, action, thoughts etc of each n every soul is captured in **Akashic Records**, the Akashic records are a compendium of all human events, thoughts, words, emotions, and intent ever to have occurred in the past, present, or future.

Citing references from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_records):

> In theosophy and anthroposophy, the Akashic records are a compendium
>   of all human events, thoughts, words, emotions, and intent ever to
>   have occurred in the past, present, or future. They are believed by
>   theosophists to be encoded in a non-physical plane of existence known
>   as the etheric plane. There are anecdotal accounts but there is no
>   scientific evidence for the existence of the Akashic records.[1](http://www.akashicrecordsofsouls.com/)[3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/is-chitragupt-of-yamlok-mentioned-in-any-scriptures)
>
> Akasha (ākāśa आकाश) is the Sanskrit word for 'aether' or 'atmosphere'.

Also as described Akashic records site [here](http://www.akashicrecordsofsouls.com/):

> The Akashic Records are the energetic records of all souls about their
>   past lives, the present lives, and possible future lives. Each soul
>   has its Akashic Records, like a series of books with each book
>   representing one lifetime. The Hall (or Library) of the Akashic
>   Records is where all souls’ Akashic Records are stored energetically.
>   In other words, the information is stored in the Akashic field (also
>   called zero point field). The Akashic Records, however, are not a dry
>   compilation of events. They also contain our collective wisdom.

In Hinduism we do refer to [Chitragupta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitragupta) as a person who keeps track of each & every action of everyone.

> Chitragupta (Sanskrit: चित्रगुप्त, 'rich in secrets' or 'hidden
>   picture') is a Hindu god assigned with the task of keeping complete
>   records of actions of human beings on the earth. He is god of justice.
>   Upon their death, Chitragupta has the task of deciding heaven or the
>   hell for the humans, depending on their actions on the earth.
>   Chitragupta Maharaj (Chitragupta ) is the patron deity of Kayasthas, a
>   Hindu caste of India and Nepal.

More can be read about him in the following question: [Is Chitragupt of Yamlok mentioned in any scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/is-chitragupt-of-yamlok-mentioned-in-any-scriptures)

Comment: What is this "Akashic Records"? Sorry, but only Hindu sources allowed here. Flagging.

Comment: @sv Feel free to do anything that makes you happy. In Hinduism Chitragupta and Yamaraja keep records of every action done by every jiva on Earth so that they can be accounted. This can be viewed as akashic records. As stated Akasha (ākāśa आकाश) is the Sanskrit word for 'aether' or 'atmosphere'.

Comment: @Just_Do_It citing sources for Chitragupta and Yamaraja keeping records would be better. Though Akashic records relates with Sanskrit word "Aakash", the concept is based on Blavatskian not the Hinduism one.

Answer (score -3):

God doesn't know about your thoughts, only you are aware about it. Sri Yukteswar told about the workings of thought reading to his disciple Paramahansa Yogananda.

Autobiography of a Yogi / Chapter 12 - [Years in My Master’s Hermitage](https://www.ananda.org/autobiography/#chap12):

> Unless necessary I do not invade the seclusion of others’ minds. **Man has the natural privilege of roaming secretly among his thoughts. The unbidden Lord does not enter there**; neither do I venture intrusion.

---

Similar to above, Bhagavad Gita also suggests that, the supreme One 'acts' disinterested and secluded to the worldly matters:

> BG 9.9 - O Arjuna, those actions (Karma-s) don't bind Me, as "I" am indifferent (**disinterested**) & detached to those actions
>   BG 13.15 - Reflecting through the senses, [yet] devoid of all the senses; **disinterested**; the sustainer of all; Without 3 modes, and the consumer of 3 modes

To be able to "know" anyone's thoughts, mind & senses are required. However, the omnipresent is devoid of all senses. Hence, it merely acts as a witness.

Comment: Really? I am surprised. Did he literally meant that? What I can read from above statement is that God just witnesses your thoughts without altering them.

Comment: @RaRa Open the link to read the full part, he doesn't mention anything about altering, he literally meant that. At the time of giving boons, God doesn't give boon by reading the thoughts of person, God gives what is being asked and thought secretly by the person. If I remember correctly, exception was the case of Kumbhakaran when he asked for boon, in that case I believe Brahma dev read the mind of Kumbhakaran and altered what he was about to speak.

Comment: God doesn't give boon by reading the thoughts of person, God gives what is being asked and thought secretly by the person   - That's ok but that does not mean that God does not know the intent/thought. This answer appears to be against what scriptures say. @ChinmaySarupria

Comment: The quality of "all-knowing" that God is attributed with would mean nothing is unknown to him. The only reconciliation possible to this statement is God does not influence the thoughts unduly.

Comment: @Rickross yes it is clearly against what scriptures say..atleast the way he reads that statement.

Comment: Nothing is unknown to him and in fact contradicts to what Krishna says in Bhagavad Gita. Its just that he doesnt interfere in our thoughts and actions and has given freewill to Jivas....

Comment: I think what you quoted doesn't imply God doesn't know our thoughts.For example, i have never been to Kashmir, but doesn't mean i am not aware of Kashmir at all.

Comment: Technically this answer is correct. Not sure why so many downvotes. @Rickross, no it's not against the scriptures. See I have added verses from Gita, which implies that the omniscient is not interested in the worldly matters. God probably may have capability of knowing thoughts/actions, but doesn't indulge. However, it always remains as a witness (as per Gita).

Comment: I hv not downvoted this answer but if the answer is saying "God does not know" thn it is clearly against what scriptures say..  Q is also not abt whether God interferes or not .. OP is asking whether God knows or not.. @iammilind